# I have a flutter project, I want to run on iPhone but when "flutter run" it says the path "/artifacts/engine/ios" does't exist. but the path exist

Tags: ios, flutter

Xcode's output:
↳
    The path
    /⁨Users⁩/⁨username/⁨Desktop⁩/⁨teeth_form⁩/⁨flutter⁩/bin/cache/artif
    acts/engine/ios does not exist
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build
    description

Answer (score 0):

try change your flutter channel with the command:
 flutter channel master
and run
 flutter doctor